# fazer com que o botao chame a funçao

Tags: python, pyqt-5

Ola,

Eu estou usando o pyqt5 e estou tentando sem sucesso que o o botao chame a funçao.
alguem pode me ajudar?

Eis o codigo

Obrigado

```
(...)

class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()


        uic.loadUi("work1.ui", self)

        self.line = self.findChild(QLineEdit, "lineEdit")
        self.button = self.findChild(QPushButton, "pushButton")
        self.label = self.findChild(QLabel, "label")
        self.textBrowser = self.findChild(QTextBrowser, "textBrowser")
        
        global text
        
        
        
        
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: wordfinder("Mary"))

        self.show()

    def clicker(self):
        wb = load_workbook('book.xlsx')
        ws = wb.active
        

        self.textBrowser.setText(str(ws["C2"].value))
        #self.button.clicked.wordfinder("Mary", Self)
        #wordfinder("Mary")
        

    def wordfinder(searchString):
        wb = load_workbook('book.xlsx')
        ws = wb.active
        #text1 = str(self.line.text()) 
        #print(text1) 
        
        for i in range(1, ws.max_row + 1):
            for j in range(1, ws.max_column + 1):
                if searchString == ws.cell(i,j).value:
                    print("found")
                    print(ws.cell(i,j))
```

Comment: A função que você quer chamar é wordfinder() com o parâmetro "Mary" correto?

Comment: sim exatamente. Obrigado